# weird ui-sref behaviour: old params still remain at URL although trying to change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

This is my state definition:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app.reports', {
            url: '/reports?param1&param2',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/report/views/reports.html',
            controller: 'reportController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
```

When I click these,

```
<a ui-sref="app.reports({param1:'param1'})">
```

it's working as I expected, it calls my service factory function which I defined and called from reportController and gets data from REST service and shows it. And the URL is http://.../#/app/reports?param1=param1

After clicking this,

```
<a ui-sref="app.reports({param2:'param2'})">
```

it's not working. My "factory" function isn't called, no any REST call, so data doesn't change. And somehow, the URL is http://.../#/app/reports?param1=param1&param2=param2

Is this weird?

**EDIT:** You can see it here, http://plnkr.co/edit/wmfgqY9hCmIj9Bk39NaP?p=preview

Comment: Here is the explanation and the answer: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3171#issuecomment-265946923

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your second `<a ui-sref>` tag, your param 1 is `undefined`, therefore the resulting URL would be `http://..../#/app/reports?UNDEFINED&param2=param2`.

You'll need to define param 1 because here it thinks that param 2 depends on it.

I hope this clears things up!